# flex netconnect ( Property onTest not found on flash.net.NetConnection and there is no default value )

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

Having this code:

```
nc.call("test", new Responder(onCallSuccess,onCallFailed), "user1");
```

and

```
public function onTest(id:String):void {
   Alert.show("test called from server");
}
```

Results in:

```
`ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property onTest not found on flash.net.NetConnection and there is no default value`.
```

How could I fix this?
Ive tried a lot of different approaches, it seems that the data is send from server application correctly but flex cannot "eat it"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `nc.client = this`, so the server knows where to call methods.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, `onTest` is callback method. Callback methods must be contained in `client` property of `NetConnection` instance. The default value for client is `NetConnection` instance itselft. That's why `onTest` is trying to be called, but it does not exist. You have 2 possible solutions here:

1.Extend NetConnection class with your custom one and define `onTest` method there. And use your custom class instead.

```
class MyNC extends NetConnection
{
     public function onTest(id:String) {...}
     ...
}
```

2.Create class, which will be client for NetConnection and define `onTest` there.

```
class Client
{
    public function onTest(id:String) {...}
}
...
var nc:NetConnection = new NetConnection();
nc.client = new Client();
```